# Aplicacion en Vue 3 no se muestra correctamente en Safari MacOS

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js, macos, vue3

testeando el siguiente formulario de Vue 3 en navegador Safari, no me muestra el valor de los inputs ni del placeholder, por otro lado en chrome de macOs si muestra el valor de los inputs al escribir pero no muestra el valor de placeholder

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form class="contactus" @submit.prevent="saveMessage">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="titleFormAbout">
          {{ $t("contactus.componentForm.text1") }}
        </h1>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 30px;">{{ $t("contactus.componentForm.text9") }}</p>
      <input type="text"  class="form-control formContact" :placeholder="$t('contactus.componentForm.text2')" id="name" required />
      <input type="email"  class="form-control formContact" :placeholder="$t('contactus.componentForm.text3')" id="email" required />
      <vue-tel-input
        v-model="phone"
        id="phone"
        class="formControl formContact"
      ></vue-tel-input>
      <br />
      <textarea
        class="form-control formContact"
        name=""
        id="message"
        rows="10"
        :placeholder="$t('contactus.componentForm.text5')"
        required
      ></textarea>
      <br />
      <vue-recaptcha  
        style="margin-bottom: 14px" 
        @validate="validated"
        />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <input
            class="form-control "
            type="Submit"
            id="submitButton"
            :value="$t('contactus.componentForm.text6')"
            disabled
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <button class="form-control clear" @click="clearForm" >
            {{ $t("contactus.buttonClear") }}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <div class="alert" id="Response" role="alert"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import VueRecaptcha from "../forms/vue-recaptcha.vue";
const hostName = location.port =="" ?location.protocol + "//" + location.host:'http://'+location.hostname+':3000';

export default {
  components: {
    VueRecaptcha,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      config: {
        headers: {
          //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validated(){
      const htmlElement=document.getElementById('submitButton');
      htmlElement.classList.add('submit');
      htmlElement.disabled=false;
    },
    clearForm() {
      document.getElementById("name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("email").value = "";
      document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].value = "";
      document.getElementById("message").value= "";
    },
    saveMessage() {
      //alert(document.getElementsByClassName("highlighted")[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML)
      const responseBox = document.getElementById("Response");
      const params = new FormData();
      const countryPhone = document.getElementsByClassName("highlighted");
      var countryPhoneid = "+52";
      if (countryPhone.length > 0) {
        countryPhoneid =
          countryPhone[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
      }

      params.append("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
      params.append("email", document.getElementById("email").value);
      params.append("phone",countryPhoneid + " " + document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].value);
      params.append("message", document.getElementById("message").value);
      axios
        .post(hostName + "/api/contact", params, this.config)
        .then((response) => {
          responseBox.innerHTML = this.$t("contactus.componentForm.text7");
          responseBox.classList.add("alert-success");
          setTimeout(() => {
            responseBox.classList.remove("alert-success");
          }, 5000);
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          responseBox.innerHTML = this.$t("contactus.componentForm.text8");
          responseBox.classList.add("alert-danger");
          setTimeout(() => {
            responseBox.classList.remove("alert-danger");
          }, 5000);
          console.log(err);
        });
      responseBox.hidden = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        responseBox.hidden = true;
      }, 5000);
      document.getElementById("name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("email").value = "";
      document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].value = "";
      document.getElementById("message").value = "";
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].placeholder=this.$t('contactus.componentForm.text10');
    const listcountry = document.getElementsByClassName("vti__dropdown-list");
    listcountry[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[137].classList.add("highlighted");
    document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].required = true;
    document
      .getElementsByName("telephone")[0]
      .addEventListener("input", (textin) => {
        const telephone = document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0];
        //console.log(parseInt(textin.data));
        //console.log(Number.isInteger(textin.data));<
        if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(textin.data))) {
          //  console.log(telephone.value);
        } else {
          telephone.value = telephone.value.slice(
            0,
            telephone.value.length - 1
          );
        }
      });
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.contactus .submit {
  background: #008b9e;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.contactus .formContact{
    border: 2px solid #BAD1FF;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
}
.contactus .clear {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-weight: bold;
}
.contactus .titleFormAbout {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #00a8c6;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-left: 12px;
  text-transform: none;
}
form.contactus {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;

}
.contactus form li {
  color: black;
}
.contactus .alet {
  text-align: center;
}

.contactus .contactus p{
  text-align: justify;
}
</style>
```

En la siguiente imagen muestro como se ve en los navegadores de otros sistemas operativos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el resultado en Safari y chorme de macOs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe una configuración especial para los formularios en Safari o en MacOs? o alguna Idea que tengan del ¿por que se este generando este problema ?

Answer (score 0):

VUE es un framework JavaScript por lo cual contiene métodos y funciones especiales, una que mas se utiliza es el v-model que es usado para el manejo de datos en los input

y los otro son los  data() que se encarga en el manejo de todos los datos que maneja

para obtener un datos en un metodo se utiliza el prefijo this.input_nombre

en el templete se usa {{ input_nombre }}

el uso del siguiente codigo no se usa
:placeholder="$t('contactus.componentForm.text2')"
en vez de eso puede usa :placeholder="input_correo"

le recomiendo que vea este video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzegdHgNEF4

```
 <template>
    
        <form class="contactus" @submit.prevent="formulario()">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="titleFormAbout">
                    {{ input_nombre }}
                </h1>
            </div>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 30px;">{{ $t("contactus.componentForm.text9") }}</p>
            <input type="text" v-model="input_nombre" class="form-control formContact"  id="name" required />
            <input type="email" v-model="input_correo" class="form-control formContact"  id="email" required />
            <vue-tel-input v-model="phone" id="phone" class="formControl formContact"></vue-tel-input>
            <br />
            <textarea class="form-control formContact" name="" id="message" rows="10"  required></textarea>
            <br />
            <vue-recaptcha style="margin-bottom: 14px" @validate="validated" />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input class="form-control " type="Submit" id="submitButton" :value="$t('contactus.componentForm.text6')" disabled />
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button class="form-control clear" @click="clearForm">
guarda                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <br />
            <div class="alert" id="Response" role="alert"></div>
        </form>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    //import Vue from "vue";
    
    //import vue2Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone'
    //import 'vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css'
    
    export default {
        computed: {
    
          
        },
        components: {
            //vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
        },
        data() {
            return {
                //añadirmos los datos de v-model
                input_nombre: 'Marcos',
                input_correo: 'once.marcos@gmail.com',
                input_Reporte_id:98
    
            }
        }
        mounted() {
            //this.consulta();
            this.data_foraneo();
            if (this.$route.params.id > 0) {
                this.show_registro(this.$route.params.id);
            } else {
                this.anadir_registro()
            }
        },
        methods: {
    
            anadir_registro() {
                this.validacion = "";
                this.editar_dato = false;
                this.limpiar_form();
                this.mensaje_formulario = "Añadir un nuevo registro"
            },
            
            formulario() {
                this.is_enviar = true
    
                const data = {
                    nombre: this.input_nombre,
                    correo: this.input_correo,
                };
    
                axios.post(`/Api/Reporte/${this.input_Reporte_id}`, data)
                    .then(response => {
    
                            const datos = response.data;
                            if (response.data.errors) {
                                //this.$toastr.warning("Verifique los datos", "Verifique los datos");
                                //this.validacion = response.data.errors;
                            }
                            if (response.data.id) {
                                //this.validacion = "";
                                //this.$toastr.success("operaciónn exitosa", "Datos modificados");
                                //this.consulta(this.page);
                                //window.history.back();
    
                            }
                        },
                        (err) => {
                            console.log("Err", err);
                            //this.$toastr.warning(err, "Error en el servidor");
                            //this.$toastr.warning(err.message, "Error en el servidor");
                        });
    
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```